# Ошибка сохранения файла в Geany (Linux Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, c++11, geany

Установил на Ubuntu 15.04 Geany версии 1.25.

При попытке сохранения файла выскакивает ошибка, как на скриншоте ниже. Подскажите, как можно пофиксить это.

Заранее благодарю.
[image: Ошибка (скриншот)]

Comment: А если в корне хомяка создать и сохранить?

Comment: Может быть проблема не в ОС, а в IDE, которую используете? Посмотрите куда она файл пытается сохранить, попробуйте в этой директории `touch any_filename.txt` выполнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, каталог и файлы, в которые вы пытаетесь внести изменения, принадлежат другому пользователю.

один из возможных вариантов «решения» — изменить принадлежность этих файлов/каталогов:

```
$ sudo chown $USER /путь/к/файлу/и/или/каталогу ...
```

или рекурсивно для всего содержимого каталога:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /путь/к/каталогу ...
```